# Does the norm of the product give information about the norm of the matrices?

Tags: matrices, inequality, numerical-methods, normed-spaces

Let $\|\cdot\|$ be an operator norm subordinate to $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ and $A,B\in \mathcal{M}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$. Also, let us assume that $\|AB\|\to 0$. Now, by the multiplicative inequality for operator norms, $\|AB\|\leq \|A\| \|B\|$. With the norm of the product tending to $0$, can we say anything about the product of the norms?

Comment: What do you mean by $\|AB\| \to 0$?  Are $A$ and $B$ sequences of matrices?  Matrix valued functions, perhaps?

Comment: Yes, I am using iterative methods for convergence

Comment: I don't think you can say much, since $AB$ could very well be $0$ even if $A,B$ are non-zero.

Comment: So you can also assume that as the product $AB$ iterates, $\|AB\|\to 0$.

Comment: @ArnaudD. could you elaborate? Do you mean "WITH $A,B$ non-zero"?

Comment: @hungryformath Yes sorry. I edited my comment.

Comment: Ok, well lets try this: Let $AB=(x-y)(w-z)$. Thus, $\|AB\|=\|(x-y)(w-z)\|$. If the LHS converges to zero, the obviously the RHS must tend to zero as well. However, with $\|(x-y)(w-z)\|\to 0$, can we say anything about the individual products (i.e. $(x-y)$ and $(w-z)$ )?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $A$ is a singular matrix and $B=null(A)$. Then, $AB=0$, even if $\|A\|>0$ and $\|B\|>0$.

Basically, nothing can be said about the product of norms, because it completely depends on the volume of the subspace shared by $A$ and $B$.

Comment: The question assumes a more general $B$ than you do, so this response does not seem to be on point. Can you make this more relevant to the given question?